# How to get time interval as seen in message from a NSDate Eg 2m, 3h, Tuesday, 2014-06-01

Tags: ios, time, nsdate, intervals, message

Is there a framework or API to give time time interval like 2m, 3h, Tuesday, 2014-06-01 from a given NSDate to current NSDate. It's widely used in iMessages and Mail App. It's also used in other apps, I am just seeing if there is a framework before I try to write one for myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use [this](https://github.com/billymeltdown/nsdate-helper) category. It is very helpful for what you are looking for.

For example this line of code:

```
NSString *displayString = [NSDate stringForDisplayFromDate:date];
```

produces the following kinds of output:

```
 - ‘3:42 AM’ – if the date is after midnight today
 - ‘Tuesday’ – if the date is within the last seven days
 - ‘Mar 1’ – if the date is within the current calendar year
 - ‘Mar 1, 2008’ – else ;-)
```